# How can I create tiles that scale to multiple resolutions?

Tags: java, flash, tiles, svg

I am trying to create a multiplayer version of the popular Flash game N in Java. However, I'm not sure how to create a tileset that will scale up. Are the tiles for N pre-drawn or are they defined with mathamatical formulas in code?

I do see how they would scale up in Flash if they were pre-rendered. So if anyone has any ideas how I should go about creating the tileset, or how they are created in the game please let me know.

You can check out the game [here](http://n.infunity.com/).

Comment: Doesn't really matter how they did it, it matters how you want to do it in your game. Asking *"How to make tilesets using formulas"* would be a better question for the site than this one.

Comment: Agreed; I tweaked the question title and content a bit to be a little more in-line with what I think you were actually asking anyhow.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The creator of N actually put together a few tutorials explaining a little of the technology they used.

Tutorial A is about the collision detection used (separating axis theorem) but may be useful to you.

http://www.metanetsoftware.com/technique/tutorialA.html

Tutorial B explains more about the tile shapes used and from the looks of it, they are just a tileset.  Some sample source code can be found at the bottom of the page.

http://www.metanetsoftware.com/technique/tutorialB.html

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create tilesets that scale to many resolutions, you can look into creating your tiles from a vector graphics format (like SVG, which you did tag your original question with) rather than a raster format like PNG, et cetera.

You can, at load time (or possibly as a build step if you have a fixed set of known resolutions), load the vector graphics data, create geometry for it using your rendering API, and render out the tileset to a texture which then you can then use in your game as you would any normal tileset -- this way you save yourself the cost of re-rendering a bunch of tile geometry that likely never changes.

This *also* has the advantage of allowing you to use both pre-defined tiles in SVG and tiles that you design mathematically via some formula or script for procedurally generating them -- the script or formula just needs to produce the same style of point/triangle/whatever data that you're feeding to the tileset pre-renderer from SVG. Or, if you'd like to do just eschew pre-defined tiles entirely you can build them all procedurally.

As Byte56 commented, even though you are attempting to create a game in the style of another, you don't have to do things *exactly the same way* that game did, so long as it looks and functions similarly enough for your needs, any technique is appropriate.

There are a [few](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6287650/rendering-svg-with-opengl-and-opengl-es) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4129932/rendering-vector-graphics-in-opengl) on SO about rendering SVG (more if you hit up your favorite search engine).